# Dynamically Alter column datatype from nvarchar to decimal if a condition is satisfied sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to dynamically alter the data type of my column "ROE 2" in table tb1  to decimal if Column header is like "ROE ".

My column header will increase over time

Is it possible?

Comment: I've no idea what "My column header will increase over time" is meant to mean.

Comment: This means.. over the time my column will increase to ROE 2, ROE 3, ROE 4

Comment: Numbered columns are generally a bad sign in a data model. Usually, it's an indication that the data should be modelled as more *rows*, so that all of the "same" type of data goes into the *same* column, and also (possibly, if order/number is important) an additional column to contain 2, 3, 4, etc, that's currently wound up embedded in the column *names* (I.e. it may be data but it's ended up being stored as metadata instead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the catalog view `sys.columns` to retrieve all your wanted columns from your table and construct an `ALTER` statement as a string:

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE tb1 ALTER COLUMN [' + name + '] Decimal(18,2) NULL'
FROM sys.columns
WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('tb1')
AND name LIKE 'ROE%'
```

From there you can grab the queries and run them manually or open a `CUSROR` and iterate each statement to run them with an `EXEC` call.

Comment: Wouldn't cursor be slow?

Comment: I'd say not really unless you have thousand tables to update. Most of the runtime will probably spent more on changing the column type.

Comment: I have created a do while that will run the top 1 query and will delete that query till there are any rows in the query output . thanks I am taking your query as answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to write dynamic SQL for that..read it from here http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-dynamic-sql-part-2

Comment: This is not the answer. I am asking is it possible to ALTER COlumn if only column is like ROE 2, ROE 3?

Comment: yes seems posisble..there is table in SQL server called INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  . Query it with your table name and   compare the column name return with your pattern and then execute alter .