# How to update data types in SQL from a returned list

Tags: sql, list, types

I made a database and realized made a mistake where whole bunch of tables have `nvarchar(255)` data types in them. They were supposed to be datetime. I am trying to modify all of them by running a simple code.

First I ran the below code to identify all the tables and the relevant column names which have the word "date" in them as I know these are the columns who's data types needs to be changed:

```
select * 
from MyDatabase.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c 
where c.COLUMN_NAME like '%date%'
```

I looked at the list and confirmed none of the columns have any data in them. Only some of them have NULL in them. Which I can delete those data if needed. Also only 3 in the returned list are not Null able; the rest are Null able. I can modify the not Nullable ones manually if its going to matter.

I was thinking like running a code like:

```
select * 
from MyDatabase.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c 
where c.COLUMN_NAME like '%date%' and c.IS_NULLABLE = 'yes'

ALTER COLUMN c.COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%date%' DATETIME [NULL] -- for the Nullable items
```

With above code I was trying to use the logic from the below link:
[How do you change the datatype of a column in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626899/how-do-you-change-the-datatype-of-a-column-in-sql-server)

Nevertheless, I know my above implementation is incorrect. Could anyone help me with the proper way? Thanks in advance

Comment: check if this question/answer (which you should have found before asking this question) helps you: [Dynamically Alter column datatype from nvarchar to decimal if a condition is satisfied sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33252358/dynamically-alter-column-datatype-from-nvarchar-to-decimal-if-a-condition-is-sat)

Comment: What kind of sql database service are you using?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio v18.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mysql you could this. You can achieve the same results in other sql database services, just the syntax may be different.

```
select CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', c.TABLE_NAME, ' MODIFY COLUMN ', c.COLUMN_NAME, ' 
DATETIME;') 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c 
where c.COLUMN_NAME like '%date%' and c.TABLE_SCHEMA='database_name'
```

Basically you're retrieving all the columns with the word date and then using the `CONCAT` function to build alter queries. Then you just need to run the resulting queries.

Comment: Thank you. I had to revise the code just a bit:

Comment: Thanks. I had to reviseit:   
Select (Select CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',c.TABLE_NAME,' ALTER COLUMN ',c.COLUMN_NAME,' datetime;'))
From
 INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE 
 C.COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%date%'  
and c.TABLE_NAME='options' –- this is to focus on Options table

I added the missing SELECT. Also due to my version I used ALTER COLUMN instead of MODIFY COLUMN. The code returned below results:

ALTER TABLE Options MODIFY COLUMN createdat DATETIME;

So the code is coming up nicely but its just displaying the code; its not executing it

Comment: Yes, you just need to copy the resulting code and run it. Very simple

Comment: haha Awesome. I actually tried to add Execute function to run all those strings but didn't actually think of selecting them with mouse and executing. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Not a problem!  :)